# How to detect if in ANY candle in the past 'n' candles meet a certain requirement?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'd like to check if ANY candle in the past 'n' candles meet a certain condition.

E.g. let's check if any close in the latest 20 candles was higher than 'x':

```
x = 2
n = 20
condition = [ANY of n] > x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`barssince()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_barssince) and an example showing how to use it [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-trigger-a-condition-only-when-a-number-of-bars-have-elapsed-since-the-last-condition-occurred).

You can also count the number of occurrences of a condition in the last n bars using:

```
sum(cond ? 1 : 0, len)
```

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.

Comment: is there a way to make the LEN relative? E.g. "LEN = x where x >=5 and <= 10" to check candles between t5 and t10?

Comment: Yes, [you can pass a dynamic length to `sum()`](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-20554/). Just be sure it is protected against `na` values using `nz()` and against values <1 using `max(1, _)`. [This FAQ entry](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-calculate-values-depending-on-variable-lengths-that-reset-on-a-condition) has code showing those techniques in use, which you could adapt.